# Non-trivial exemple of Hölder continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen the following concept appear quite often in mathematics:

> A function $f:I\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be *Hölder continuous* if there are constants $\alpha$ and $M$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|^\alpha$$ for all $x,y\in I$.

What are some examples of Hölder continuous functions?

Comment: Any realization of Brownian motion is Hölder continuous.

Comment: Any continuously differentiable function or Lipschitz function is Hölder continuous -- not sure what you mean by "non-trivial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice example is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). It is [Hölder continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666577/prove-that-cantor-function-is-h%C3%B6lder-continuous), with exponent $\displaystyle\alpha=\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}$.

Answer (score 4):

$x^{\alpha}$ for $x>0$ and 0 otherwise for $0 < \alpha <1$ is Holder continuous of order $\alpha.$

Answer (score 1):

Another example is $\arcsin x $ that is $1/2$ H"older continuous in $[-1,1]$.