# About a Lipschitz property $\|f^{\mu}(x)-f^{\mu}(y)\| \leq L^{\mu}\|x-y\|^{\mu}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

For a function $f(x)=[f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_m(x)]^T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ where $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is a real-value function, $f(x)$ is Lipschitz, i.e., there exists a positive real constant $L$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$.

Then, the question is whether there exist the following inequations
$$\|f^{\mu}(x)-f^{\mu}(y) \|\leq L^{\mu}\|x-y\|^{\mu}, \forall \mu>1,$$
and
$$\|f^{\mu}(x)-f^{\mu}(y)\| \leq L^{\mu}\|x-y\|^{\mu}, \forall \mu<1$$
where $f^{\mu}(x)=[f_1^\mu(x),f_2^\mu(x),\cdots,f_m^\mu(x)]^T$.

Thanks very much.

Comment: For any $\mu>0$, the power (not exponential) function $x \mapsto x^\mu$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R_+}$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we need $f\ge0$ if $\mu$ is not an integer, which I will assume.

> $\mu > 1:$

Simple counterexample in dimension 1. let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$, $y=1$, and $\mu=2$. Then
the wanted inequality is
$$ |x^2 - 1| \stackrel{?}{\le} C(x-1)^2$$
Lets put $x=1+\epsilon$, for $\epsilon>0$. Then this reads
$$ \epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon\stackrel{?}{\le} C\epsilon^2 $$
which is easily seen to be  wrong for any $C>0$, once $\epsilon\ll1$.

In fact, the inequality implies that $f$ is everywhere differentiable with derivative $0$, so the only such $f$ are (locally) constant.

> $\mu \in (0,1)$:

This is true, at least up to a constant. Recall that [$x^\alpha$ is $\alpha$-Hölder with constant 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202662/x-alpha-as-an-example-of-an-alpha-h%c3%b6lder-continuous-function) So for each coordinate, we have
$$ |f_i^\mu(x) - f_i^\mu(y)| \le |f_i(x) - f_i(y)|^{\mu} \le L^\mu |x-y|^\mu$$
which implies the result with a potentially different constant depending on the precise choice of norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: Is $\mu$ an integer or a real? And if real positive or arbitrary??

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos, I did not notice that OP asked for both $\mu>1$ and $\mu<1$. My answer only addresses $\mu>1$.

Comment: I am sure the other case is false too!

Comment: Well I have no idea for $\mu<0$. but its true for $\mu\in(0,1)$ (maybe the constant is wrong). Since $x^{\alpha}$ is $\alpha$-Hölder @GeorgeTsoutsinos