# Evaluate $\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\frac{|\sin^{\alpha}(t)-\cos^{\alpha}(t)|}{|\sin(t)-\cos(t)|^{\alpha}}), \alpha \in [0,1]$.

Tags: limits, trigonometry, inequality

I came across the following limit in an exercise and was wondering how to solve it:

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\frac{|\sin^{\alpha}(t)-\cos^{\alpha}(t)|}{|\sin(t)-\cos(t)|^{\alpha}}), \alpha \in (0,1]$

Could it have something to do with the modulus of inequality?

I tried all the usual methods (l'hopital and some trig identities) but can't seem to get the desired result (=0). Would be nice if someone could give me some tips :)

PS: For anyone wondering what the original question was, it was to show that: for the function $f(x) = |x|^\alpha$ on the interval $[0,1]$, with $\alpha \in (0,1]$. Show that $\exists C > 0$ s.t. the modulus of continuity of $f(x)$ satisfies:

$\omega(f,h)\leq Ch^\alpha$, $h > 0$.

Determine the minimal possible value of $C$. (The limit came from my attempt to show $C \geq 1 \Rightarrow \min\{C\} = 1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|x|^\alpha$ is differentiable at $x=\frac1{\sqrt 2}$, so in particular Lipschitz. Thus,
$$ |x|^\alpha = \frac1{2^{\alpha/2}} + O\Big(x-\frac1{\sqrt 2}\Big), \quad \text{as }x\to \frac1{\sqrt 2}.$$

Since

\begin{align}\cos t &= \frac1{\sqrt 2} - \frac{t-\frac\pi4}{\sqrt 2} + O\Big(\left|t-\frac\pi4\right|^2\Big), \quad \text{and} \\ \sin t &= \frac1{\sqrt 2} + \frac{t-\frac\pi4}{\sqrt 2} + O\Big(\left|t-\frac\pi4\right|^2\Big), \quad \text{as }t\to \frac\pi{ 4}, \end{align}
the numerator is $O(t-\frac\pi4)$, while the denominator is eventually (as $t\to \frac\pi4$) bounded from below by $\frac12|t-\frac\pi4|^\alpha$. So the limit  is zero.

For the original problem: let $C_*$ be the infimum of all possible $C$s. If $\omega(f,h)\le C|h|^\alpha$, then since $|h|^\alpha = f(h)-f(0) \le \omega(f,h),$ we must have $C\ge 1$. On the other hand,  [a standard argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202662/x-alpha-as-an-example-of-an-alpha-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function) shows $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|^\alpha$, so $C_*\le 1$. Hence, $C_*=1$.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the thorough response. :)

Comment: @noke glad to help! On Math.SE, if you find an answer helpful and solved your problem, you should upvote the answer (click on the up arrow next to the answer). Also, you should choose the most helpful one and mark it as accepted (click the tick ✔️  next to the answer) You can vote once per answer, but unfortunately you can only "accept" one answer. Hope you find Math.SE to be a useful resource!

Comment: @Calvin_Khor, I would love to, but as this is my first question, I don't yet have the reputation to upvote / mark correct anwsers. Will do as soon as I do though. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @noke oh, I know you need some reputation to downvote, but I thought you didn't for an upvote. Anyway, welcome to Math.SE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}(\frac{|\sin^{\alpha}(t)-\cos^{\alpha}(t)|}{(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^{\alpha}}), \alpha \in (0,1].
$$
In this way you can get rid of the absolute value and just compute
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{\sin^{\alpha}(t)-\cos^{\alpha}(t)}{(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^{\alpha}}, \alpha \in (0,1].
$$

I will compute this limit, and the same will apply if you compute the left limit. Applying L'Hopital rule:

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{\sin^{\alpha}(t)-\cos^{\alpha}(t)}{\sin(t)-\cos(t)^{\alpha}}=
\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{\alpha \sin^{\alpha-1}(t)\cos (t)+\alpha\cos^{\alpha-1}(t)\sin(t)}{\alpha(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^{\alpha-1} (\cos(t)+\sin(t))}.
$$
Note that since $\alpha \in (0,1]$, $\alpha -1<0$, and therefore

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}\frac{\alpha \sin^{\alpha-1}(t)\cos (t)+\alpha\cos^{\alpha-1}(t)\sin(t)}{\alpha(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^{\alpha-1} (\cos(t)+\sin(t))}=\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+}(\sin(t)-\cos(t))^{1-\alpha}\frac{\alpha \sin^{\alpha-1}(t)\cos (t)+\alpha\cos^{\alpha-1}(t)\sin(t)}{\alpha (\cos(t)+\sin(t))}=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I seemed to have miscalculated the derivative (I had a subtraction in the denominator). :)