# Hölder continuity of the Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, cantor-set

The Cantor function (which I will define recursively below) is Hölder continuous and the exponent there is ln(2)/ln(3).

The function is defined as the limit function of a sequence of functions, where $f_{n}$ looks as below: 
 \begin{cases} 
     f_{n-1}(3x/2)  & 0 \leq x\leq 1/3\\
     0.5 & 1/3\leq x\leq 2/3 \\
      0.5 + f_{n-1}((3x-2)/2) & 2/3\leq x \leq 1
   \end{cases}

I've proved that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to the Cantor function and that $||f_{n} - f_{n-1}||_{\infty}$ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{2^n}$, but I have no idea where to proceed from there. Any inputs will be appreciated. My final goal, as I mentioned above, is to prove Hölder continuity with Hölder exponent ln(2)/ln(3).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to prove Holder continuity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that Cantor function is Hölder continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666577/prove-that-cantor-function-is-h%c3%b6lder-continuous)